# Adding attachment to Jira's api

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to attach a file to a Jira case, using their API.  I am doing this in Drupal 6 (PHP v.5.0).  Here is the code I have:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$header = array(
  'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
   'X-Atlassian-Token: no-check'
);
$attachmentPath = $this->get_file_uploads();
//$attachmentPath comes out to be something like:
//http://localhost/mySite/web/system/files/my_folder/DSC_0344_3.JPG

$data = array('file'=>"@". $attachmentPath, 'filename'=>'test.png');
$url= 'https://mysite.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/20612/attachments/';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->get_jira_headers());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ,$data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "myusername:mypassword");

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$ch_error = curl_error($ch);
```

The problem is that the $result comes out as false, and the $ch_error states that it couldn't open the file.  Does this error have something to do with Drupal or something to do with how I'm sending my request to Jira?  BTW, if I use an absolute path, though, like this:

```
$attachmentPath = 'C:\wamp\www\mySite\web\sites\mySite.net\files\my_folder\DSC_0333.JPG';
```

The upload works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$data = array('file'=>"@". $attachmentPath . ';filename=test.png');
```

This was a bug with cURL PHP <5.2.10, you can see this in the PHP bug tracker: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48962 (And in the comments you see, that it has been fixed)

And if you use PHP 5.5.0+ you can use this:

```
$cfile = new CURLFile($attachmentPath);
$cfile->setPostFilename('test.png');
$data = array('file'=>$cfile);
```

You can also see this in a JIRA comment: [JIRA Comment](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-30765?focusedCommentId=586291&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-586291)

Also i think you want to change this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->get_jira_headers());
```

to this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I actually accidentally added the bounty to this question, while intending it to add it to the other question I added.  But, a deal is a deal and I'm just glad it works!

Comment: @jason You're welcome! yeah, i think that's just then main goal to get it to work!

Comment: It return  cURL Error: malformed